# Rails - why SQL return incorrect result?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join

I have the table **items** and to this table is associated table **item_views**, here's the structure:

```
  create_table "item_views", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

When I run on the database this AR query:

```
current_user.items.joins(:item_views).where("item_views.created_at > ? AND item_views.created_at < ?", date_from, date_to+1.day).count
```

then is generated following SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" INNER JOIN "item_views" ON "item_views"."item_id" = "items"."id" WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 AND (item_views.created_at > '2013-09-10' AND item_views.created_at < '2013-09-20');
```

Here are data in the **item_views** table:

```
select * from item_views;
1|1|2013-09-10 09:52:11.703811|2013-09-10 09:52:11.703811
2|1|2013-09-13 22:55:56.574696|2013-09-13 22:55:56.574696
3|1|2013-09-15 13:14:19.221074|2013-09-15 13:14:19.221074
4|2|2013-09-16 13:05:39.972383|2013-09-16 13:05:39.972383
5|3|2013-09-16 13:11:25.466117|2013-09-16 13:11:25.466117
6|1|2013-09-16 19:12:44.846686|2013-09-16 19:12:44.846686
```

(id, item_id, created_at, updated_at)

The query should return the value **3**, but instead of that it returns **5** - it looks like in the query is ignored the condition `"items"."user_id" = 1`.

How is that possible, or do I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: can you see what those 5 records are and post their values also? THanks

Comment: Which database is this? What timezone are you in and what timezone is the database in?

Comment: `mu is too short` it's SQLite database, I am not sure about the timezone (it's running on my localhost).

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why it would return 5. `4` looks like the right answer.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "items" INNER JOIN
     "item_views"
     ON "item_views"."item_id" = "items"."id"
WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 AND
      (item_views.created_at > '2013-09-10' AND item_views.created_at < '2013-09-20');
```

All 6 rows in your data meet the condition on date.  Yes, `'2013-09-10 09:52:11.703811'` is greater than `'2013-09-10'`.  Perhaps the intention is:

```
WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 AND
      (date(item_views.created_at) > '2013-09-10' AND
       date(item_views.created_at) < '2013-09-20'
      );
```

which is more efficiently expressed as:

```
WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 AND
      (item_views.created_at >= '2013-09-11' AND
       item_views.created_at < '2013-09-20'
      );
```

Are you sure there is not one more `1` row?  In any case, you should run the query with `select *` instead of `select count(*)` to see what it returns.

Comment: @muistooshort . . . I suppose that is possible.  The actual SQL create table statement is not included in the question.